# Looking for a plugin for drag-drop upload images, drag-sort and remove

Tags: jquery, image, file-upload, graphics

I'm looking for a jQuery/HTML5 plugin where users can basically pull together a compilation of images for design inspiration... like an inspiration-board or mood-board

So drag-drop upload, upload from multiple sources, draggable, multi-selectable etc

From my search so far, Filepicker.io looks good but will require quite a bit of customization.

Anyone know of any other options?

Answer (score 4):

For file uploading specifically, my favorite tool is http://www.dropzonejs.com.

dropzone.js is an open source jQuery plugin that provides drag'n'drop file uploads with image previews in HTML5.

It supports multiple image uploads and automatically generates thumbnails in the browser.

You can configure max file size, thumbnail dimensions, and file types that are accepted. Works in modern browsers and IE 10+.

This would only get you halfway there... after the files are uploaded then you have more options to build out a custom interface for your user to tag them, organize them, etc.